# What book do you suggest for modern grammar?

Tags: discussion, resource-request

Please, if possible, introduce books on the following topics.

Modern Grammar, Syntax, Morphology

I want to use your experience. Otherwise googling is easier but useless.

Comment: I thought you were at university–I read it somewhere–in any case, what English grammar/syntax etc books do you already possess? Are there any reasons why you find them unhelpful? What level of English are you: B1, B2 or C1? The more details we have the better.

Comment: I would suggest, judging by the questions you have posted so far on this site, that you are at an average Intermediate level. Therefore, you shouldn't be deep diving before you can swim confidently underwater (my variation on a common aphorism) Look for grammar books at level B1 and B2 written by English native speakers.

Comment: I am. We have already studied grammar in use (all three books) but they are too old. Unfortunately, I didn't learn much from the third book, Advanced Grammar in Use, it was very complicated and unpractical, the concepts and examples were very scattered.

Comment: The series "Grammar in Use" by Raymond Murphy are updated, but even so the rules of good grammar don't necessarily change from one decade to the next. The Advanced Grammar in Use by Martin Hewing is very good, but as the name suggests it is Advanced level. I disagree that the examples are scattered, they are relevant to the unit being studied.

Comment: Grammar in use is one of the best grammar books I've ever seen in my life. It has three levels (Elementry, Intermediate and Advance) (British and American).